# What's the connection between Community and Captain America?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier, community-2009

While watching the latest Captain America film, *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, I noticed a cameo by Danny Pudi, who plays Abed in the TV show *Community*. I didn't take this as a meaningful event, until I watched the latest *Community* episode ("Basic Sandwich"). In one part of it, they meet a locked up computer genius, who built a huge computer called Raquel, who is capable of "feeling". It seems both the room and the computer share great similarity to Arnim Zola as he appeared in *The Winter Soldier*.

To compare, I give you some snapshots taken from *Community* (left) and *The Winter Soldier* (right):

[image: First comparison image (community-left, captain america-right)]

[image: Second comparison image (community-left, captain america-right)]

**Can anyone explain these occurrences? Why and how this link was made?**

Comment: Community is famous for parodying movies and TV shows, and being extremely self-referential.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a recent article in [Empire Magazine](https://www.empireonline.com/features/captain-america-the-winter-soldier-spoilers-easter-eggs/p13), Winter Soldier Director Anthony Russo spilled the beans on a number of "easter eggs" included in the movie;

> **Anthony:** *“Did Danny beg us to be in the movie? I think we begged him! We love Easter Eggs. When Redford opens the fridge, there’s a
>   Newman’s Own dressing in there. Then there's the gravestone at the end
>   of the movie… We like layers. So [casting Community star Danny Pudi]
>   was a nod to all the Community fans. You know Abed loves cameos, so we
>   figured [we’d put him in]. We hadn’t officially decided [whether that
>   was Abed], but **knowing (Community creator) Dan Harmon, he’ll find a
>   way to use it.”***

It's pretty clear that the inclusion of a similar looking computer room and an upright computer (complete with a crayonised version of the computer face seen in C.A.II) was an in-joke between Community team and the Winter Soldier team.

Comment: You haven't included the main link between the two - that the main directors for Community also directed The Winter Soldier.

Comment: @drrdizzle - Keen mentioned it in his answer, directly below this one.

Comment: I know that, but it seem that being as yours is the top rated answer and the accepted answer, it should probably include all the neccessary information, unless there is some kind of rule against duplicating information from other answers.

Comment: @drrdizzle - There's no formal rule, but  I've always felt that cannibalising other people's answers takes away from the effort they put in. I'll occasionally do it if it supplements or enhances the points I've *already made* or conflicts directly with a point I've already made.

Comment: The random downvoter was me when I originally saw that you did not include the fact that the Russo Brothers directed and produced Community. It's now been over an hour and I cannot undo my downvote.

Answer (score 5):

The directors of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, Anthony Russo and Joe Russo, worked on *Community* previously.  See their IMDb pages: [one](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0751577/) and [two](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0751648/).  They directed and executive produced many episodes of *Community* before they started working on *Captain America: TWS*.  So they gave Danni Pudi (*Community's* Abed) a cameo.  Not sure if they purposefully included the similar old computer settings though, but it's possible.

Comment: The *Community* episode was likely produced after *The Winter Soldier*. Both released April 2014.